# What is the significance of "creates a new creation" in Numbers 16:30?

Tags: numbers, 2-corinthians

A Faithful Version Numbers 16:30

> But if the LORD **creates a new creation**, and the earth opens her mouth and swallows them up with all that they have, and they go down alive into the pit, then you shall understand that these men have provoked the LORD.

How's this new creation compared with the following new creation?

2 Corinthians 5:17

> Therefore, if anyone be in Christ, he is a **new creation**; the old things have passed away; behold, all things have become new.

Comment: My own view is that you, correctly, sensed a spiritual allusion to a new creation. And those whom the earth swallowed up, went straight to their destiny and would never partake in that new creation. But it is a sensitive allusion, not overt, and I do not think anything can be 'proved' in the wording of the text, as such. Hence my comment, not an answer. But I agree with what you sense. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Num 16:30 should not be separated from the previous two verses which read:

> **28** Then Moses said, “This is how you will know that the LORD has sent me to do all these things, for it was not my own doing: **29** If
> these men die a natural death, or if they suffer the fate of all men,
> then the LORD has not sent me. **30** But if the LORD brings about
> something unprecedented, and the earth opens its mouth and swallows
> them and all that belongs to them so that they go down alive into
> Sheol, then you will know that these men have treated the LORD with
> contempt.”

The phrase in the Hebrew of V30: בְּרִיאָ֞ה יִבְרָ֣א (literally: "a new thing creates") is quite uncomplicated to translate as the verb is a Qal imperfect.  The Faithful Version's rendering "creates a new creation" appears to be an unfortunate attempt at being poetic when the original Hebrew is not poetry at all.  Most versions get V30 correct as follows:

- NIV: But if the LORD brings about something totally new ...
- NLT: But if the LORD does something entirely new ...
- ESV: But if the LORD creates something new ...
- BSB: But if the LORD brings about something unprecedented ...
- NASB: But if the LORD brings about an entirely new thing ...
- NKJV: But if the LORD creates a new thing ...
- HCSB: But if the LORD brings about something unprecedented ...

Note that בְּרִיאָה (beriah) means a thing created, or something entirely new.  It only occurs here in the OT.  BDB offers this meaning:

> בְּרִיאָה noun feminine a creation, thing created, as preternatural,
> unparalleled; accusative of congnate meaning with verb ׳אִםבֿ ׳יִבְרָא
> י Numbers 16:30, compare בָּרָא Qal 3, Niph`al 3.

Now to 2 Cor 5:17 - Paul is discussing something entirely different from that in Num 16 - the transformation of the character, or better, the re-creation of the mind and character of the Christian following conversion, and **NOT** the destruction of evil people as per Num 16..  The context makes this abundantly clear -

> **14** For Christ’s love compels us, because we are convinced that One died for all, therefore all died. **15** And He died for all, that
> those who live should no longer live for themselves, but for Him who
> died for them and was raised again.  **16** So from now on we regard
> no one according to the flesh. Although we once regarded Christ in
> this way, we do so no longer. **17** Therefore if anyone is in Christ,
> he is a new creation.a The old has passed away. Behold, the new has
> come!